# Move given point by X,Y meters Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I currently need to calculate a new point (Longitude and Latitude) from a given point and an X and Y offset in meters in Openlayers. I tried using the [translate](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Point-Point.html) function already available on the ol/geom/Point class but the result does not look correct as the result position is different then expected.

My question is if there's any other way on ol to calculate the desired position.
I'm using ol 6.0.3.

Thanks.

Comment: The offset must be in the same units as the point coordinates, so you cannot add meters directly to longitude and latitude, you would need to transform the coordinates to a metric projection, add the offset then transform back to longitude and latitude.  Also be aware that some metric projections are not true scale at all positions (e.g. one meter on EPSG:3857 web mercator projection is only true at the equator).

Comment: Hey @Mike I'm currently using the default Web Mercator projection (EPSG:3857)  on my map view and according to the [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html) this is a metric projection I still don't get the correct results. What I'm doing is the following: var point  = new `Point(fromLonLat([-76.091308, 18.427501]));` Then applying the translation `point.translate(500, 0);` But the new point coordinates does not match the expected value. I`m doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Mercator is not metric... distance at the pole is infinite...

For small distances, you have to calculate the resolution at the point:

```
import {getPointResolution} from '../src/ol/proj.js';
let pointRes = getPointResolution(map.getView().getProjection(), 1, point);
let dx = 500 / pointRes;
point.translate(dx, 0);
```

For larger distance you have to compute the distance on the sphere along a great circle.
You can look at ol-ext lib to compute the destination point given an initial point, a distance and a bearing: using [`ol_sphere_computeDestinationPoint` function](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/blob/master/src/geom/sphere.js).

Comment: getPointResolution expects the point's coordinates `let pointRes = getPointResolution(map.getView().getProjection(), 1, point.getCoordinates());`